# Can you please help me Identify my Bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I just got a hand me down and have no idea what kind of bike it is. I would like to know what bike it is... The person that gave me the bike is claiming that its a carbon fiber frame however i know nothing about bikes... Please help! [image]

Comment: It has no decals, and it has a really bad paint job which is why its making it harder for me to identify

Comment: Have you looked in side the seat tube or something? I'd guess its aluminum.

Comment: No there's nothing that would help me identify anything

Comment: Is there a serial number stamped on the underside of the bottom bracket?  Often times that can give a hint... for instance many manufacturers have a brand identifier, year, model number, frame number scheme they follow.

Comment: Yes... Serial number is 935GA502 or 9356A502.. Numbers are blurry but its one of those two forsure

Answer (score 2):

All I can tell you is that its a 90s or early 2000's bike.

Get a magnet and see if there's any attraction to the downtube, and to the forks.  If so, its steel.
Then take out the seat tube and look down with a torch/flashlight.  If its dull silver, the frame is aluminium/alloy.  If its plastic then its carbon.

Weight might also help show what its made of - carbon is lighter than aluminium is lighter than steel.

**Details**

The seat tube has a long curved rear section to confirm to the rear wheel, making it an aero frame built for speed.

Likewise, the downtube is not round - it looks to have a boxy profile, again for aero advantages.

Conversely, the gear and brake cables are externally routed.  So its either a lower end frame, or predates when that became common in the 90s.

The pedals fitted appear to be clipless of some sort, which also suggests a racer.

Brakes look to be dual pivot, but the terrible paint job doesn't help.

Saddle will be non-original because its not a racing one, and the seatpost is now fitted the wrong way around so the most recent rider was probably too small for the frame.

**Note**:  Storing it like that, leaning the whole weight on the chainring is bad.  Please hang it or put some wheels on it.

**Next** I'd try removing some of the paint and look for decals, URLs, or a head tube badge/logo.  Hot Soapy water would be a good safe starting point.